# How to change image colors and content based on number of days?

Tags: jquery, spring, hibernate, jsf

I have Plan tab in My web application, if I click on Plan tab it will show three images for indicating service details (e.g. image1 for service 1).

Initially for the first service Image 1 will be green, by clicking on image it would show its service and plan details. Before 15 days of service date the image color change to yellow as well by clicking on image it would show its service details like service date. Service date is expired than it turns to the red color.

```
CREATE TABLE `service_plan` (
  `serice_plan_id` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `serice_plan_name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `serice_plan_rate` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `plan_details_id` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`serice_plan_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Hi, did you try my example?

Comment: Thanks for logic, actually there is a change in requirement , so i not tried, but this logic is good.

Comment: Thanks! If you think my answer solved your initial requisites, plase accept it. To mark an answer as accepted click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.

Comment: ya sure, this is good logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the JSF lifecycle you read the Service date from your DB, then put it into your backing bean (Model) and finally render the value in your browser. You can render the Service date in a hidden component (if you want) like this:

and then read this value and proccess it from javascript in order to show the color to the user. See this complete example as guidance:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
        .cgreen{ background-color: springgreen;}
        .cred{ background-color: red;}
        .cyellow{ background-color: yellow;}
        .ishidden{display:none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

        <span>Service Date (MM/dd/yyyy)</span>&nbsp;
        <input class="service-date ishidden" value="09/23/2015 14:30:00" type="text"/>
        <button id="refresh">Refresh</button>
        <br/>
        <span>Indicator</span>&nbsp;
        <div id="indicator" style="height: 50px; width: 50px; display: inline-block;"></div>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js"></script> 
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var colorCalculus = function(){

        var color = 'cred';
        var today = new Date();
        var serviceDate = new Date($('.service-date').attr('value'));

        var fifteenBackwards = new Date(serviceDate.getFullYear(), serviceDate.getMonth(), serviceDate.getDate() - 15);

        if(today < fifteenBackwards){
            color = 'cgreen';
            }
        else if(fifteenBackwards <= today && today <= serviceDate){
            color = 'cyellow';
            }

        $('#indicator').removeClass('cred cgreen cyellow');
        $('#indicator').addClass(color);
    };

        $('#refresh').click(function(){colorCalculus();});

        colorCalculus();

    });
</script>       
</body>
</html>
```